# How to solve SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE using mercurial when connecting to remote server

Tags: ssl, mercurial

### Problem

I am trying to connect to client's remote mercurial repository. The error I get when connecting to it wit any command:

```
abort: error: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:997)
```

I am on Macbook air M1 using mercurial version:

```
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 6.0.1)
```

This is the latest version currently. Server with remote repository is a debian distribution using mercurial 4.8:

```
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 4.8.2)
```

This version is the stable version for debian as it is stated on https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Download
I only get this problem on mac. On another windows computer mercurial version is 5.6 and it works fine.
How to solve this?